# How to get and post parameter from url

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I got a page link like `www.example.com/resetPassword?pass=33` and I can get this value from controller method with using `@RequestParam` method.

Problem is I also need this parameter(pass) value when I post this page(form).When I post below form url changes to `www.example.com/resetPassword` but I want also paramter as `www.example.com/resetPassword?pass=33`.Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Here is my form;

```
<form:form action="resetPassword.htm" role="form" method="POST">
....
</form:form>
```

My controller method;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resetPassword.htm*", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView resetPassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("pass") String pass){
if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")){
 //
}
else if(request.getMethod().equals("POST")){
//
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It doesn't matter if the parameter was sent with GET or POST.

Answer (score 0):

This is in general a bad idea. You are breaking restful convention.

The different request types normally have different behaviour, don;t try and combine them.